# Problem burning bootloader to ATmega chip using nano/uno

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-mega, arduino-nano, bootloader

I designed a custom PCB that has the chip, an oscillatorm, decoupling capacitors, and all other connections for the ATmega along with the rest of my circuit. I followed all steps in the tutorial for burning the bootloader to my ATmega chip but when using a nano to program I get an error about getsync() that supposedly means the reset isnt working. I then used the same wiring with an uno like in the examples and I got a different error this time where it goes yikes then something about not recognizing the chip. This is apparently indicative of a wiring or oscillator problem but all those things appear to be correct. I'm not sure what to try next or what could be wrong

Used this tutorial as well as the actual arduino page https://www.electronoobs.com/eng_arduino_tut6.php

Used this tutorial next since I am using ATmega328PB
https://www.circuito.io/blog/atmega328p-bootloader/

Here's the error I get
Arduino: 1.8.9 (Windows Store 1.8.21.0) (Windows 10), Board: "ATmega328, Yes (UART0), 328PB, BOD 2.7V, LTO disabled, 16 MHz external"

\nas01.itap.purdue.edu\puhome\My Documents\ArduinoData\packages\arduino\tools\avrdude\6.3.0-arduino17/bin/avrdude -C\nas01.itap.purdue.edu\puhome\My Documents\ArduinoData\packages\MiniCore\hardware\avr\2.0.3/avrdude.conf -v -patmega328pb -cstk500v1 -PCOM5 -b19200 -e -Ulock:w:0x3f:m -Uefuse:w:0b11110101:m -Uhfuse:w:0xd6:m -Ulfuse:w:0b11111111:m

avrdude: Version 6.3-20190619
         Copyright (c) 2000-2005 Brian Dean, http://www.bdmicro.com/
         Copyright (c) 2007-2014 Joerg Wunsch

```
     System wide configuration file is "\\nas01.itap.purdue.edu\puhome\My Documents\ArduinoData\packages\MiniCore\hardware\avr\2.0.3/avrdude.conf"

     Using Port                    : COM5
     Using Programmer              : stk500v1
     Overriding Baud Rate          : 19200
     AVR Part                      : ATmega328PB
     Chip Erase delay              : 9000 us
     PAGEL                         : PD7
     BS2                           : PC2
     RESET disposition             : dedicated
     RETRY pulse                   : SCK
     serial program mode           : yes
     parallel program mode         : yes
     Timeout                       : 200
     StabDelay                     : 100
     CmdexeDelay                   : 25
     SyncLoops                     : 32
     ByteDelay                     : 0
     PollIndex                     : 3
     PollValue                     : 0x53
     Memory Detail                 :

                              Block Poll               Page                       Polled
       Memory Type Mode Delay Size  Indx Paged  Size   Size #Pages MinW  MaxW   ReadBack
       ----------- ---- ----- ----- ---- ------ ------ ---- ------ ----- ----- ---------
       eeprom        65    20     4    0 no       1024    4      0  3600  3600 0xff 0xff
       flash         65     6   128    0 yes     32768  128    256  4500  4500 0xff 0xff
       lfuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  4500  4500 0x00 0x00
       hfuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  4500  4500 0x00 0x00
       lock           0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  4500  4500 0x00 0x00
       calibration    0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00
       signature      0     0     0    0 no          3    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00
       efuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  4500  4500 0x00 0x00

     Programmer Type : STK500
     Description     : Atmel STK500 Version 1.x firmware
     Hardware Version: 2
     Firmware Version: 1.18
     Topcard         : Unknown
     Vtarget         : 0.0 V
     Varef           : 0.0 V
     Oscillator      : Off
     SCK period      : 0.1 us
```

avrdude: AVR device initialized and ready to accept instructions

Reading | ################################################## | 100% 0.02s

avrdude: Device signature = 0xffffff (retrying)

Reading | ################################################## | 100% 0.02s

avrdude: Device signature = 0xffffff (retrying)

Error while burning bootloader.
Reading | ################################################## | 100% 0.02s

avrdude: Device signature = 0xffffff
avrdude: Yikes!  Invalid device signature.
         Double check connections and try again, or use -F to override
         this check.

avrdude done.  Thank you.

Here's the PCB schematic and wiring picture
[image: PCB Schematic]

[image: Wiring]

Comment: Post a link to the tutorial that you followed.

Comment: Edited original post to add tutorial

Comment: The tutorial is fine, except for reset pin which he should've used a 10K resistor. post the exact error message(s) and a picture of what you have on breadboard or PCB...

Comment: Updated again, added new tutorial I tried and the pictures

Comment: I had the same "invalid device signature" problem and using minicore library solved it. if you followed all steps correctly, maybe the chip is damaged.

Comment: Yeah I replaced the chip and then was able to burn the bootloader fine. But now when programming I get an error that programmer isn't responding. I'm using this guide: https://www.instructables.com/id/Program-ATmega-328-Using-Arduino-Arduino-As-ISP/